# SQL SELECT SUM BETWEEN 1 Year from now to start ot the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I'm kinda stuck with a little query to get the SUM of the time period I want. So it already works but I want that it's automatically between 1 year from now and the beginning of the year.

```
SELECT SUM(N_EXCL), S_CUSTNO, S_CUSTNAME1, D_INVOICEDATE 
from sao.INVOICE_P i 
WHERE  D_INVOICEDATE >   DATEADD (year, -1, getdate ())  
AND D_INVOICEDATE < DATEADD (month , -6 ,Getdate () ) 
GROUP BY S_CUSTNO, S_CUSTNAME1, D_INVOICEDATE
```

Currently I would have to change the query every month but I try to find a way to avoid it.

Ok. Maybe i wasn't clear enough. My problem is the -6 i have to write down. I want to switch it to a parameter that will automatically change up the date so that i get data from 01.01.2021 - 22.06.2021. So same date, but different year.

Comment: this query not working? dateadd function in getdate() so this automatic

Comment: Hint: `DATEFROMPARTS` and `YEAR(GETDATE())`.

Comment: WHERE  D_INVOICEDATE >   DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)

Comment: So you want to get from 1st of January previous year till current date previous year?

Comment: We call that "hard coding". `dateadd(month, 1-month(getdate()), dateadd(day, 1-day(getdate()))` is the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should be able to do this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(N_EXCL), S_CUSTNO, S_CUSTNAME1, D_INVOICEDATE 
from sao.INVOICE_P i 
WHERE D_INVOICEDATE between DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) AND DATEFROMPARTS(getdate(), 1, 1) 
GROUP BY S_CUSTNO, S_CUSTNAME1, D_INVOICEDATE
```

So instead of using `where` `and` I'm using `where` `between`. And I'm checking for todays date last year till 1st of January current year.

If you need from 1st of January previous year you can use:

```sql
between DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate() -1), 1, 1) AND DATEADD(year, -1, getdate())
```